# Using AWS services to create subdomains on the fly to host a site on S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

**INFO:** I am working on an app built in php which facilitates users to create HTML templates and publish them on web.As the templates would be static I thought of using amazon S3 for storing them as it can host static websites and has good infrastructure overall for the application.br/>

**QUERY:** I am facing an issue while publishing it to the web.I want the template to be published as a subdomain on my domain,for eg: I own www.ABC.com,I ask the user to name the template,if he names it as mysite,I publish his template as mysite.ABC.com(similar for all users).Now,I can store the template in the S3 bucket using `putObjectFile` in the aws s3 api,but I am not sure how can I create a subdomain(**on the fly**) and publish it on that domain.(I want to automate the process for the user). Also,can I make the bucket as `hosting static website` using the API?
Earlier,I worked with cpanel and cpanel API's allow us to create domains and do a FTP to the domain with the content,I am not clear how can I achieve it here.

**RESEARCH:** The success till now I have achieved is,I have hosted a site using the **S3 console**.Using the AWS services I have moved the files to a `bucket` with the name same as the subdomain of the user.I want now to have the bucket endpoint changed to the subdomain.

**REFERENCE:** [This](http://app.imcreator.com/edit) website does the same,they create a directory like structure and publish the website on web.I don't know if they host it on Amazon,but I want to achieve something similar.Hope I am clear and get some guidance.

Thank you for the attention

Comment: are you looking for Route 53 (http://aws.amazon.com/route53/)?

Comment: I have the basic knowledge of route53,but I want to be able to create domains.Does Route 53 allow me to create domians?I did not find any API associated with it.

Comment: maybe this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=470514&tstart=0#470514 ?

Comment: the PHP2 SDK reference for Route 53 is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/namespace-Aws.Route53.html

Comment: btw, you do not have to use AWS for DNS things. If your host allows you to change DNS settings for your domains then you can use that instead. all you need to do it seems is to point your domain to the bucket.

Comment: But pointing takes time to propagate right?I want it to be reflected instantly as the user can see it published.Please look at the REFERENCE I added so that my point is more clear.I will go through route 53 in the mean time'

Comment: For example when I enable `Static Web Hosting` I get a S3 bucket end point thorough which I can access my website like this -> mysite.gobiggi.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.Instead of this I want a custom **subdomain** say only the bucket name.Is that possible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35137/discussion-between-killabug-and-akonsu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched a similar scenario some time ago but I was unable to use S3 for this because of a S3 limitation.

To host a static website on S3 on a custom domain or subdomain, you need to create a bucket with a name that matches that domain. And because each S3 account is limited to 100 buckets, you will only be able to host those many domains or subdomains on a single account.

Based on the use case you described, I suspect this S3 limitation will also force you to find another solution.

In my case, the solution was to set up an EC2 instance that proxies requests to S3 after rewriting them. For example if someone requests:

`http://mysite.abc.com/file.html`

that goes through our EC2 server where the request is rewritten and forwarded to S3 as something like:

`http://ourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mysite.abc.com/file.html`

**UPDATE:**

There are several proxy servers that you could use for this but I would recommend nginx as it worked great in our case. To get started, check out the following nginx docs:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the limitation!As you said I need to do a proxy,but can you please elaborate on how exactly I can achieve it?I am still a newbie working on the cloud and aws stuff!

Comment: I updated my original answer to include links to the nginx docs as you could use this server to proxy the requests. This setup is not specific to the cloud or aws, it would be the same to proxy and rewrite requests to any backend server. Those docs will help you get started but you will probably need to do more research on this and post other specific questions, either here or on serverfault if you get stuck on a specific point.

Comment: Just to make sure if I am going the right way,earlier I used cpanel and its services(API's) to create subdomains(**on the fly**) and transfer files via FTP.Is the approach highlighted by you better or I can go with this one?Offcourse I don't yet have a cpanel on Amzon,bt thats a different problem probably!

Comment: The approach I suggested is not necessarily better in your case. It really depends on your needs and experience. Each method has advantages and disadvantages. As advantages in storing the data directly to S3 and using this proxy method I would mention that your EC2 instance will not need a persistent storage attached to it (EBS), S3 has great data durability and reliability, the load on your server will probably be smaller than when using cPanel so you might use a cheaper instance and it is easier to load balance the load between multiple servers than it is with cPanel.

Comment: I am going through your suggestions,but would the functionality work fast in terms of speed?As subdomain creation will take time and I don't want the user to wait for the results to propagate!!Do you say its the best way to go while using AWS and amazon EC2? I have accepted your answer and will post any specific questions when help needed(I believe I will definitely need it)

Comment: Speed wise, you can set this up so any changes propagate instantly, without any delay caused by DNS. To do this you could use a wildcard DNS entry, something like *.abc.com that points to your proxy server on EC2. This way, if someone tries to access subdomain.abc.com there won't be any DNS delay and the changes will be instantly visible.

Comment: Just to confirm is the limit of 100 buckets applicable to **paid accounts** also or is it default for all? The other concern is when the user asks for his own domain(Once he has his template he can switch to his own domain),so will it be easy to do that?

Comment: All AWS accounts have a limit of 100 buckets - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html. As for moving to their own domain, it's possible to do that as long as their domain points to your proxy server.

Comment: I just thought of a hack or trick whatever you call it.I will have a single bucket pointing to a subdomain say `sites.abc.com` and have the templates as multiple folders inside a bucket like `sites.abc.com/site-1`,`sites.abc.com/site-2`.Is this a valid use case to go ahead.Sorry,I believe I am irritating you but,I am just trying to identify the possibilities!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm happy to help you out. Although using subdirectories instead of subdomains does work, it's not always a good idea to go down that path as it has implication on security (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and possibly SEO. It really depends on the type of content that you plan to host in those locations.

Comment: Yes I thought about SEO,but as far as its a subdomain I believe we are not much worried about the SEO,only once the user has a custom domain I want to have it SEO compliant.Also,when the user switches to a custom domain do you switch the bucket as AWS says **bucket name and domain name** has to be same or you just change the pointing for that entry? I visited your site `Sitedity.com` and its really very cool! :)

Comment: Thanks :) As long as you're using the EC2 proxy server to handle custom domains, when one of your user switches to custom domains you just need to point their domain to your proxy. You could host their files in `sites.abc.com/custom-domain.com` and your proxy can forward any requests for `www.custom-domain.com` and `custom-domain.com` to that location.

Comment: Does route53 come into picture anywhere?do we need to use those API's for Route 53?I have started working and will post as and when I get stuck!Please keep checking AWS section for answering those! :P Thanks a ton for the guidance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35255/discussion-between-dcro-and-killabug)

Comment: hats off to you @dcro